# Linear programming (lpSolve) error using Big Data in R

Tags: r, lpsolve

I trying to optimize my model with 30000 variables and 1700 contraints, but i got this error´s when i put some more contraints.

```
n<-lp ("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs)$solution
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 129.9 Mb
```

I´m working in win 32 bit, 2gb ram.
What can i do to work  and optimize my model using a large dataset?

Comment: Depending on where your problem comes from,
you may be able to decompose it (approximately) into a set of smaller problems.
This is the case, for instance, for linear programs
coming from some stochastic optimization problems 
([progressive hedging](http://mpc.zib.de/index.php/MPC/article/download/85/39)).

Answer (score 1):

That's a tiny machine by modern standards, and a non-tiny problem. Short answer is that you should run on a machine with a lot more RAM. Note that the problem isn't that R can't allocate 130 MB vectors in general -- it can -- it's that it's run out of memory on your specific machine.

I'd suggest running on a 64-bit instance of R 3.0 on a machine with 16 GB of RAM, and see if that helps.

You may want to look into spinning up a machine on the cloud, and using RStudio remotely, which will be a lot cheaper than buying a new computer.